# OpenCv IOS Mach-o Linker Error Cocoapods: "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:"

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, cocoapods

I am trying to run an opencv sample that uses optical flow: https://github.com/manikal/thorrson

This project uses the opencv framework via cocoapods. However, after installing the library via cocoapods i get a Mach-O linker error.

It looks like the error is coming from something within the opencv library but I am new to these errors and am not sure.

The error log is included:

```
Showing All Messages
Check dependencies

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thorrson-cecwugbfwvtybddoxpqfewlijwgc/Build/Intermediates/Thorrson.build/Debug-iphoneos/Thorrson.build/Script-70640BB6194D77BC78E87857.sh
    cd /Users/John/Desktop/thorrson
    /bin/sh -c /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thorrson-cecwugbfwvtybddoxpqfewlijwgc/Build/Intermediates/Thorrson.build/Debug-iphoneos/Thorrson.build/Script-70640BB6194D77BC78E87857.sh


Ld /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Thorrson-cecwugbfwvtybddoxpqfewlijwgc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Thorrson.app/Thorrson normal arm64
    cd /Users/John/Desktop/thorrson
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export 

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in ViewController.o
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in ViewController.o
  "cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&) in ViewController.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in ViewController.o
  "cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController opticalFlow] in ViewController.o
  "cv::circle(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController opticalFlow] in ViewController.o
  "cv::cornerSubPix(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>, cv::TermCriteria)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController opticalFlow] in ViewController.o
  "cv::swap(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController opticalFlow] in ViewController.o
  "cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const", referenced from:
      -[ViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController opticalFlow] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



Activity Log Complete    2/11/17, 9:37 AM
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve it?